# Можно ли реализовать аналог std::endl?

Tags: c++, потоки-данных, операторы

### Цель

Я хотел написать аналог `std::endl`, который бы вставлял символ `'\n'`, но не вызывал бы `.flush()`.

### Ожидания

Я думал, что можно будет использовать запись типа `std::cout << my::endl;`

### Что я пробовал

Написал класс, у которого есть `operator<<`

```
namespace my {
struct endl {
    template<class Stream>
    friend Stream& operator<<(Stream& stream, endl) {
      return stream << '\n';
    }
};
}  // namespace my
```

Но тогда я должен писать так `std::endl << my::endl{};`. А я хочу писать без `{}`, как в стандартной библиотеке, но не могу придумать, как это сделать.

Приходит в голову только решение с определением нового оператора в `namespace std`, но так делать нельзя.

**Есть другие способы?**

Comment: а поему просто не написать `namespace my { const char endl = '\n'; }` ? или нужно только с функциями и шаблонами?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21129162/tell-endl-not-to-flush

Comment: Некоторые потоки имеют строчную буферизацию. Они автоматически делают `flush` при получении `'\n'`.

Comment: тогда неважно, как это символ пришел?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы не хотите совсем просто, без шаблона? Какой в нем смысл в данном случае?

```
namespace my {
    ostream& endl(ostream& stream) { return stream << '\n'; }
}
```

Comment: Просто у меня используются разные потоки: `ostream`, `string_stream`, `fstream` и тд. Разве такая реализация подойдет тогда?

Comment: Конечно, это все дочерние от `ostream`. Раз есть оператор `<<`, значит, это output stream :) Нет, конечно, если вы хотите переопределить оператор для, скажем, входного потока... Но это вряд ли :) См. https://ideone.com/HBgczA

Comment: @Harry а зачем так суперсложно?

Comment: @KoVadim Что именно суперсложно? Почему не просто выводить `\n`? :) Ну, мало ли, вдруг ТС захочет чего-то еще. Его вопрос, по сути, немного шире, чем задан — думаю, вы это понимаете...

Comment: я понимаю, но мне кажется, люди любят переусложнять.

Answer (score 2):

`std::endl` — это функция, принимающая и возвращающая `std::ostream`, реализовать ее аналог, вставляющий символ `\n`, но не вызывающий `flush`, можно следующим образом:

```cpp
template<class CharT, class Traits>
std::basic_ostream<CharT, Traits>& endl(std::basic_ostream<CharT, Traits>& os) {
    os << '\n';
    return os;
}
```

Comment: Раз уж шаблон (т.е. и для широких символов тоже), то нельзя использовать просто `os << '\n';`, надо `os.put(os.widen('\n'));`

Comment: Я так и написал :)

Answer (score 2):

Все очень просто:

```
namespace my {
    constexpr char endl = '\n';
}
```